# When trying to edit a configurable product ... lost on this error... how to fix it

Tags: magento

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/magento2/www/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 43

Comment: which magento2 version are you using?

Comment: 'Magento  2.2.8'

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 43

**Process**

We were importing a csv with column "configurable_variations" and values = "sku=costdai-ama-dail-p10-moon-stone-sp0000,sphere=0.00,contact_lens_color_name=Moon Stone|
sku=costdai-ama-dail-p10-moon-stone-sn0050,sphere=-0.50,contact_lens_color_name=Moon Stone"

**Solution and Reason**

The reason of above error is the child product (costdai-ama-dail-p10-moon-stone-sp0000) does not have values assigned for attribute "contact_lens_color_name=Moon Stone"

So if we set the values to child product and try reimporting again. The parent product will be created with 2 child products assigned.
We can see the child products on admin when we edit the parent product, under Configurations -> Current Variations